# starting knowledge for topology

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

So I want to start self-studying topology. What do I have to necessarily have some base knowledge in? So which specific mathematical areas should i be decent/good in? Also I'd happily take any suggestions on where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set theory is fundamental

Comment: You don't need a lot of set theory though. If you get the Seymour Lipschutz book, it will teach you the set theory that you need.

Comment: A good rigorous course on real analysis (at the undergrad level) would probably give the necessary background and “mathematical maturity”.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Where would i attend such a course?

Comment: @duck I didn't mean you need to literally attend a course... you asked what subjects you should know to start studying topology, 'undergrad-level real analysis' is my answer.